# How to sort div, depending on the values that are contained in their children?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am outputting data from a file using `.map()`, so to get all the values the parent I use `.forEach()` (Otherwise, only one div with `class="price"` will be selected, instead of 20).
I need to sort all div that contain child with the amount from smallest to largest.

I am getting the child like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach((v => (Number(v.textContent))));

console.log(Number(v.textContent));

12    
31   
25     // a number is printed on each line of the console
42
3
41
```

But I don't know how to sort the parent div based on the value of the child.

Comment: Can you use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), passing in a compare function that looks at the children?

Comment: How? I don't know how to do this, so I ask. Initially, the file does not have this data, which is in the child element. I calculated them myself and added them to the child element. This data is only there, and I need to sort the parent div by this child data.

Comment: I searched a lot and read about `.sort()` and just `(a < b) ? - 1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;` but don't know how to apply to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can convert your NodeList from querySelectorAll to an Array then you can use array methods as normal:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sort Nodes By textContent Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<p class="price">12</p>
<p class="price">31</p>
<p class="price">25</p>
<p class="price">42</p>
<p class="price">3</p>
<p class="price">41</p>
<script>
    const prices = [...document.querySelectorAll('.price')]
        .map(v => Number(v.textContent))
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);
    console.log(prices)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can switch the sort function to `b - a` if you wanted descending order instead.

---

If you wanted to actually replace the DOM elements with the sorted elements you could do something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sort and Replace Nodes In DIV By textContent Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <p class="price">12</p>
    <p class="price">31</p>
    <p class="price">25</p>
    <p class="price">42</p>
    <p class="price">3</p>
    <p class="price">41</p>
</div>
<script>
    const sortedPriceNodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.price')]
        .sort((a, b) => Number(a.textContent) - Number(b.textContent));
    document.getElementById("container").replaceWith(...sortedPriceNodes);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Assuming your `.price` elements are not so neatly arranged:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sort and Replace Nodes Anywhere By textContent Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:lightblue">
    <p class="price">12</p>
    <div style="background-color:lightcoral">
        <p class="price">31</p>
    </div>
    <p class="price">25</p></div>
<p class="price">42</p>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey">
    <p class="price">3</p>
</div>
<p class="price">41</p>
<script>
    const priceNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
    const sortedPriceNodes = [...priceNodes]
        .sort((a, b) => Number(a.textContent) - Number(b.textContent));
    priceNodes.forEach((node, index) => {
        node.replaceWith(sortedPriceNodes[index].cloneNode(true));
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, the replaceWith () option is really hard, but I like it. Thanks for the options, you helped me understand where my mistake was (my function did not affect the output because of other functions that create and edit output)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="price">100</div>
     <div class="price">10</div>
     <div class="price">40</div>
     <div class="price">90</div>
     <div class="price">20</div>
     <div class="price">80</div>
     <div class="price">60</div>
     <div class="price">50</div>
     <div class="price">30</div>
<script>
const priceDivsArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.price'))
 
const sortedPriceDivs = priceDivsArray.reduce( (acc, div) => {  
            acc.push(div)
            const sortedArray =  acc
            sortedArray.sort((a, b) => (Number(a.textContent) > Number(b.textContent)) ? 1 : -1)
            return acc 
}, [])
 
 sortedPriceDivs.forEach( (element, index) => {
    console.log(`element: ${Number(element.textContent)} index: ${index}`)
})
/*
element: 10 index: 0
element: 20 index: 1
element: 30 index: 2
element: 40 index: 3
element: 50 index: 4
element: 60 index: 5
element: 80 index: 6
element: 90 index: 7
element: 100 index: 8
*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```